# Retrieving values from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple table that contains a list of 'victims' and the corresponding number of that type destroyed. I'm trying to make an output page of this information, using this code:

```
foreach( $victims as $vic )
{
   $hits = mysql_query("SELECT amount
                          FROM victims
                         WHERE victim = ".$vic );

   echo $hits;

   print "$vic: $hits <br /><hr>";
}
```

However, `hits` comes out empty. What's wrong with my SQL query?

Comment: Depending on the type of `$vic`, you more than likely have a MASSIVE SQL Injection vulnerability.  Either explicitly cast it to an integer if that's what it's supposed to be `".(int) $vic);`, or wrap it in quotes and escape it: `'".mysql_real_escape_string($vic)."'");`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($victims as $vic)
{
   $hits = mysql_query('SELECT amount
                        FROM victims
                        WHERE victim = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($vic) . '"');

   if($hits && mysql_num_rows($hits)>0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($hits)) {
               echo '<p>' . $row['amount'] . ' hits</p>';
        }
   } else {
        echo '<p>' . mysql_error() . '</p>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Some error checking would be nice, as I have a feeling that there's a query error (Since `mysql_query` returns a resource, and printing a resource results in a number)...

Comment: This comes up with 1Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /var/www/vhosts/queenofsheep.com/httpdocs/Sheep/victimlist.php on line 25
chickens: `

Comment: And that's why there needs to be error checking ;-)...  There's an error in your query...

Comment: 0 rows will just print out blank...it's difficult to tell what he truly wants to display in that case. Wasn't aware of that quirk with mysql_real_Escape_string though, I better look into it. I always use single quotes on my strings since they'll run faster than doubles (IE not looking for variables). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Single quotes don't run measurably faster...  It's a total micro-optimization to do that.  After checking the docs, I was wrong and `mres` does escape double quotes.  So it's not that bad (even though I still personally don't like to see double quotes in queries, but I guess that's just personal preference)...

Comment: It is a micro-optimization (if done as optimization). I've built the habbit and just do it all the time, so it takes no extra effort. To each his own though!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` doesn't return the actual result of your query, but rather a `resource` with which you can then access the results.

This is a typical pattern:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print($row['amount']);
```

Each call to `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns the next row of the result set. If you were expecting multiple rows to be returned, you can call this in a while loop:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print($row['amount']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no sane error checking in any of the answers, I'll put the whole thing in here:

```
foreach( $victims as $vic )
{
   $sql = "SELECT amount
               FROM victims
               WHERE victim = '".mysql_real_escape_string($vic)."'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $result or die('Query Error: '.mysql_error() . ' - ' . $sql);

   $hitsarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   if ($hitsarray) {
       $hits = $hitsarray['amount'];
   } else {
       // No row was found
       $hits = 0;
   }

   echo $hits;

   print "$vic: $hits <br /><hr>";
}
```

Oh, and this fixes the query error that caused the issue in the first place.  Note the quotes wrapping the `$vic` variable in the string, as well as the proper escaping of the string...

Comment: The error checking and security issues are certainly important. I didn't include this in my answer because I found them to be outside the scope of the question: why is `mysql_query()` not returning what the OP was expecting? Going into other issues just seems to get away from the original question. For example, I personally prefer prepared statements for queries and wouldn't be looping around my database calls, but that doesn't directly relate to what was being asked.

Comment: Fair enough @Edward...  It's still a major pet peeve of mine to see that stuff left out.  Mainly because if there was error checking the original question would not exist (since they would have seen the error and understood why nothing happened)...